# Yii2 Multiple instances of the same model

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components, yii2

I want to get multiplie instance of the same model in my controller. I saw [this wiki for Yii 1.1](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/362/how-to-use-multiple-instances-of-the-same-model-in-the-same-form/) and tried like that but in my code only last instance in form was acceble from controller my code is here (I commented code with error and variable values):

```
$model = new Person(['scenario' => 'create_update']);
$contractDate = new DatePart(); // DatePart is my own class
$contractExpirationDate = new DatePart(); // DatePart is my own class

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) &&
    $contractDate->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) &&
    $contractExpirationDate->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){

    Yii::info(Yii::$app->request->post(),'test'); // only one instance of Person and one instance of DatePart are available here
    Yii::info($_POST['DatePart'],'test'); // only last instance of DatePart (contractExpirationDate in html form) is available here
    Yii::info($_POST['DatePart'][0],'test'); // Error: Undefined offset: 0
    Yii::info($_POST['DatePart'][1],'test'); // Error: Undefined offset: 1

    $model->save();
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
} else {
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'contractDate' => $contractDate,
        'contractExpirationDate' => $contractExpirationDate,
    ]);
}
```

It is my form view in _form.php:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
//use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\widgets\ActiveForm;
use common\models\DataOperations;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Person */
/* @var $contractDate backend\viewModels\DatePart */
/* @var $contractExpirationDate backend\viewModels\DatePart */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="user-form">
    <?php
    $form = kartik\widgets\ActiveForm::begin(
        [
            'id' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'user-form-create' : 'user-form-update',
            'type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_VERTICAL,
            //'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
            'fieldConfig' => [
                //'autoPlaceholder'=>true
            ]
        ]);
    ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => 60]) ?>  
    <?= $form->field($model, 'family')->textInput(['maxlength' => 60]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'mobile')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($contractDate, 'year')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($contractDate, 'month')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($contractDate, 'day')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($contractExpirationDate, 'year')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($contractExpirationDate, 'month')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($contractExpirationDate, 'day')->textInput() ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>  
</div>
```

It is log result for:
**Yii::info(Yii::$app->request->post(),'test')**
in debugger as you seen only last DatePart available but I have two DatePart model instance (contractDate and contractExpirationDate):

```
[
    '_csrf' => 'Vl81R0ZvMk1hD1oELT9aDzkIe3EPHFgiIBJTBhA9RD8GbFM.AhlVBw==',
    'Person' => [
        'name' => 'test name',
        'family' => 'test family',
        'mobile' => '09121212123',
    ],
    'DatePart' => [
        'year' => '2015',
        'month' => 'Jun',
        'day' => 'Mon',
    ],
]
```

Comment: Means in your $model, only last value is inserted in table ?

Comment: No I only get last model from DatePart type in controller post variable. I added some information to question. (log content)

Comment: please post your view, what comes in $_POST is dependent on your form and how you submit it in the view

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Controller:

```
    $model = new Person(['scenario' => 'create_update']);
    $dates = [
        'contractDate' => new DatePart(),
        'contractExpirationDate' => new DatePart()
    ];
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        if (Model::loadMultiple($dates, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($dates)) {
            foreach ($dates as $date) {
                $date->save();
            }
            // or
            $contractDate = $dates['contractDate'];
            $contractExpirationDate = $dates['contractExpirationDate'];
            // ...... some logic

            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }
    else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'dates' => $dates
            ]);
    }
```

View Form:

```
<?= $form->field($dates, '[contractDate]year')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($dates, '[contractDate]month')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($dates, '[contractDate]day')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($dates, '[contractExpirationDate]year')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($dates, '[contractExpirationDate]month')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($dates, '[contractExpirationDate]day')->textInput() ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @zelenin I think view have some error I got this error:
Call to a member function formName() on a non-object

Comment: I think that Model::loadMultiple() not work correctly.

Comment: it is working @b24 you need to import the yii\base\Model (use \yii\base\Model)

Answer (score 6):

To complement b24 answer.

// In View Form add foreach:

```
<?php foreach ($dates as $index => $date): ?>

<?= $form->field($date, '[contractDate]year')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($date, '[contractDate]month')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($date, '[contractDate]day')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($date, '[contractExpirationDate]year')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($date, '[contractExpirationDate]month')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($date, '[contractExpirationDate]day')->textInput() ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

// - or - add index

```
<?= $form->field($dates['contractDate'], '[contractDate]year')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($dates['contractDate'], '[contractDate]month')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($dates['contractDate'], '[contractDate]day')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($dates['contractExpirationDate'], '[contractExpirationDate]year')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($dates['contractExpirationDate'], '[contractExpirationDate]month')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($dates['contractExpirationDate'], '[contractExpirationDate]day')->textInput() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be is solution for this problem :

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/53935-solved-subforms/page__p__248184#entry248184